# Mark preallocated file blocks valid in linux

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

Linux has `fallocate()` function, which allows to preallocate blocks for a file. But even though the underlying blocks may contain old data, the file appears to be filled with zeroes.

It's because on modern file systems the blocks marked as invalid, so when you read the file, OS just fills your buffer with zeroes. The only way to mark these blocks valid is to write to the file.

This is a security measure against reading other users data. It would be logical to make an exception for the root user and mark these blocks valid, when root calls `fallocate()`, but the function behavior is the same.

So I'm asking, is there a separate function available to root only to validate the preallocated file blocks?

Comment: Read from the device directly.

Comment: @alk How do I find the location of n'th block of a file? With `FIBMAP ioctl()`?

Comment: This depends on the file-system in use. For Linux this might be of help: http://serverfault.com/q/29886/143982

Answer (score 2):

> So I'm asking, is there a separate function available to root only to validate the preallocated file blocks?

Short answer is no. You have the reason in the question itself. It is basically to prevent the applications from reading the random old data and optimize the performance avoiding an additional step to validate the preallocated file blocks.

As a root user nothing is stoping you from doing a raw read on the device.